FCM in Flutter my notification received on background is displayed twice
I developed an app in Flutter, I recently implemented the functionality to manage the display of notifications received through my application. Only my phone displays 2 notifications, one overloaded by my Flutter code, the other native Flutter/Android, a priori FCM of Flutter, which uses the rendering of the Android manifest.
No problem in foreground (visible apps), it's quite overloaded by my code.
I want to display only one notification in the background.
pubspec.yalm : Flutter 3.19.3 • channel stable
 firebase_core: ^2.27.1
 firebase_messaging: ^14.7.10
 flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2

main.dart :
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(showFlutterNotification);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "Background", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
showFlutterNotification(message);
}

ManifestAndroid.xml :
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.doandgo"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_512">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="channel" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/logo" /> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/green" />
        
        <service android:name=".MonServiceMessagingFirebase" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MonActivity"
...>

Rien d'extraordinaire, vous pouvez retrouver les informations ici : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=fr#:~:text=With%20FCM%2C%20you%20can%20send,handled%20by%20the%20client%20app.
Overall, declaring MyServiceMessagingFirebase in my Android Manifest simply allows me to manage notifications when the apps is in foreground (visible), but not in background.
I tried everything, but failed to block the native display on background reception.
The display order is first the native one, then the one I overload.

If i can manage my onBackgroundMessage in android, i resolve my problem. But i declare an extended class of FirebaseMessagingService in ManifestAndroid, this class is just registered for foregroungmessage not for background...
